# FullCalendar: Customizing the calendar

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, fullcalendar

I need help customizing a Full calendar display. Like changing border colors, calendar background, adding removing Month/Day/Week Views or button?

This is what I have to display the calendar:

```
//$('#calendar').fullCalendar()

var myCalendar = $('#calendar');
myCalendar.fullCalendar();

// Adding a Simple event
var myEvent = {
    title: "New Event Added",
    allDay: true,
    start: new Date(),
    end: new Date()
};        

myCalendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent', myEvent);
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should avoid editing `fullcalendar.css` directly, so that you can update the CSS when the next versions are released.

To customize the look of FullCalendar, create a `fullcalendar-custom.css` file, which you can use to override specific styles. Just include this custom file somewhere after the `fullcalendar.css`, i.e.:

```
<link href="../fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="../fullcalendar/fullcalendar-custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

To figure out what styles you need to override, you should use *inspect element* in your browser to figure out which classes need to be modified.

---

You can remove/modify the "Month/Day/Week" view buttons when initializing FullCalendar.

For example, you could do this:

```
myCalendar.fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today title',
        right: 'month,agendaDay'
    }
});
```

For more info, see the documentation for [header](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/display/header/) and [available views](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/views/Available_Views/).

Answer (score 2):

You can find these lines in js

```
 e.color = event.color;
 e.backgroudColor = event.backgroudColor;
 e.borderColor = event.borderColor;
 e.textColor = event.textColor;
```

so, if you want to separate by color code you can use this

```
start: new Date(y, m, d+1, 15, 0), 
end: new Date(y, m, d+1, 16, 45),                                                                                       
title: 'On vacations',
color: '#777777',
backgroundColor: '#eeeef0'
```

'

Answer (score 0):

you have to edit in `fullcalendar.css` there is `.fc-header`  class you can edit that in your requirement.